# Is there a way to get the count of the number of samples within a second of each other for each row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large dataset with a datetime column and I'm trying to engineer a column which contains a count of the number of rows with a timestamp within one second of that row.

I have created a method to do this in R, but it is inefficient and contains the ugly "for i in 1:length(vector)"

```
s = c()
for (i in 1:length(df$timestamp)){
  s[i] = sum(df$timestamp >= df$timestamp[i]-1 & df$timestamp <= df$timestamp[i] + 1)
}
```

I feel like there should be a way to do this without looping and in SQL server - but I'm at a loss. Something like

```
SELECT *, count(timestamp between timestamp - 1 and timestamp + 1) as sec_count
```

So that querying:

| timestamp |
| --- |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.2 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.3 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.4 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.5 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:03 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:04 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:15 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:30 |

Would result in:

| timestamp | sec_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.2 | 4 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.3 | 4 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.4 | 4 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:01.5 | 4 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:03 | 2 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:04 | 2 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:15 | 1 |
| 1/1/2011 11:11:30 | 1 |

or similar

Comment: I have added some tables with sample data to the main body of the question

Comment: This can get tricky. Picture 3 rows with stamps 0.8 seconds apart from each other (so the first is 1.6 seconds before the last). Are you expecting counts of 2, 3, 2 for those rows or 3 for all of them?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good question but for my use it doesn't really matter, as long as it broadly catches them. The best solution would assign 3 for all of them, but I'm using this in a ml model and in reality it's usually going to be something like 49, 50,50,50...., 49 and in practice small differences don't change how the model does classifications (from using the R approach on smaller data sets).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a self-join would do the trick

```
Select A.timestamp
      ,Sec_Count = count(*)
 From YourTable A
 Join YourTable B on B.timestamp between dateadd(SECOND,-1,A.timestamp) and dateadd(SECOND,+1,A.timestamp)
 Group By A.timestamp
```

**Results**

[image]

**Update For Duplicate TimeStamps**

```
with cte as (
     Select distinct TimeStamp from YourTable
)
Select A.timestamp
      ,Sec_Count = count(*)
 From cte A
 Join cte B on B.timestamp between dateadd(SECOND,-1,A.timestamp) and dateadd(SECOND,+1,A.timestamp)
 Group By A.timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, the only problem with this method arises when you have multiple of the same timestamp - though that can be solved with another join on this table.

Comment: @Andrew i don't know enough about your data or requirements.   I don't see the issue duplicate timestamps ... don't they count as well?    That said, you could always select distinct.  See updated answer in a a moment

Answer (score 1):

For each timestamp you can determine 1 second before and 1 second after. When you have that, you can use a correlated subquery to get the result:

```sql
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, TS DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @Data(TS) VALUES ('1/1/2011 11:11:01.2'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:01.3'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:01.4'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:01.5'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:03'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:04'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:15'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:30');


;WITH data_with_max_and_min AS (
    SELECT ID, TS, DATEADD(second, -1, TS) AS min_ts , DATEADD(second, 1, TS) AS max_ts
    FROM @Data
)
SELECT ID, TS, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_with_max_and_min AS d2 WHERE d2.TS BETWEEN d1.min_ts AND d1.max_ts) AS sec_count
FROM data_with_max_and_min AS d1
```

That gives the results you show in your question.

Another way to get the same results is to join the intermediate table to itself and group. That approach looks like:

```sql
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, TS DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @Data(TS) VALUES ('1/1/2011 11:11:01.2'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:01.3'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:01.4'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:01.5'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:03'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:04'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:15'),
('1/1/2011 11:11:30');


;WITH data_with_max_and_min AS (
    SELECT ID, TS, DATEADD(second, -1, TS) AS min_ts , DATEADD(second, 1, TS) AS max_ts
    FROM @Data
)
SELECT d2.TS, COUNT(*) as sec_count
FROM data_with_max_and_min AS d1 
INNER JOIN data_with_max_and_min AS d2 ON d2.min_ts <= d1.TS and d2.max_ts >= d1.TS 
GROUP BY d2.TS
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient option (if it does not trigger an arithmetic overflow) is to use the dateadd and datediff functions.

```
count(*) over(partition by ((DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, '', timestamp)), '')))) within_min
```

Resulting in a minutes version of the output I want that runs quickly.

However, when I attempt to do this at the second scale for my data, it does unfortunately lead to the dateadd arithmetic overflow problem.